# JQuery отслеживаем загрузку страницы из другого скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<div id='modal'></div>`. В него сторонний скрипт вставляет модальное окно. Как отследить конец загрузки страницы после появления этого окна, чтобы далее работать с готовой страницей?

Пробовал отслеживать изменение так:

```
$('#modal').one('DOMNodeInserted', function () {
...
}
```

Но так мы отлавливаем начало изменений. Что не подходит.

Comment: А в стронний скрипт нельзя вставить что нибудь триггероподобное в нужное место?

Comment: Это крайний случай. Изначальная задача, реализовать без вмешательства.

Comment: а в чём заключается завершение загрузки, как вы это определяете?